# Sharing Windows Authentication between multiple applications

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, iis

I have two applications with Windows Authentication turned on. The second application is called in an iframe inside the first application. In the intranet, it is working fine as it is taking currently logged in user from the computer and not prompting for credentials. But from outside network, it is prompting for credentials for both the applications instead of asking for one. Is there anyway both the applications can share the same login.

I have only turned on Windows Authentication, other authentications methods are disabled.

[image: Scenario]

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2